# Existence of incomplete cholesky factorization

Tags: finite-element, preconditioning, matrix-factorization

What is the current state of research on the existence of incomplete cholesky factorizations (in the context of preconditioning) for symmetric positive definite matrices?

I wonder in particular whether the question of existence is settled for finite element mass matrices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Meijerink and van der Vorst](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1977-31-137/S0025-5718-1977-0438681-4/) showed that incomplete Cholesky dose not break down for $M$-matrices. As for finite element mass matrices, you will have to specify a basis to have any hope of making that claim.

Given any basis $\Phi = [\phi_0 | \phi_1 | \phi_2 | \phi_3]$ such that the mass matrix $A = \Phi^T \Phi$ is SPD, we can construct a new basis $\hat \Phi = \Phi B$ such that the new mass matrix

$$\hat\Phi^T \hat \Phi = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & -2 & 0 & 2 \\ -2 & 3 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 & 3 & -2 \\ 2 & 0 & -2 & 3 \end{pmatrix} =: K$$

is the [Kershaw matrix](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991%2878%2990098-0), an SPD matrix for which incomplete Cholesky produces a negative pivot. The transformation $B$ satisfies $B^T A B = K$, and given the Cholesky factorizations $A = L_AL_A^T$ and $K = L_K L_K^T$, is readily computable as $B = L_A^{-T} L_K^T$.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you the reading of Wang's thesis on the subject.
http://repository.tamu.edu/bitstream/handle/1969.1/ETD-TAMU-3135/WANG-DISSERTATION.pdf?sequence=1

Using local element stiffness matrices modification it allows to produce a M-matrix that approximates correctly the original global stiffness matrix (after assembly).
Hope this helps.
Tom